# How to build a chatroom which new channels can be created during server running?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chatroom

Having read posts about node.js for a long time, I tried to write my own style of chatroom with socket.io .
Here's the link, but only one channel: http://zhonglichat.cnodejs.net/
Here's what I'm thinking about:
Visitors can create new channels by typing title and clicking 'Submit'.
Then they can also visit the new channel just like visiting another chatroom.
And all these happen while the server is running. I went through the guide on socket.io , seems it's hard to create new channels. So is there any simple way via which I can make that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create a channel with the latest version of Socket.IO, the important thing is just to make clients join it, look at this code example on the server side ([from the github repo](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io)):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.join('justin bieber fans');
  socket.broadcast.to('justin bieber fans').emit('new fan');
  io.sockets.in('rammstein fans').emit('new non-fan');
});
```

As you can see the 'justin bieber fans' channel wasn't created, but clients can join it.

Comment: I just tried with node(0.6.1) socket.io(0.8.7) firefox12a, "io.sockets.in" works just as supposed, while "socket.broadcast.to" seems broken. Anyway there is such method can accomlish that task. Thanks.